# Server-Client Version Control Software for personal files

Tags: file-synchronization, version-control

I am looking for a version control software that I can run using a server-client model to do version control for my personal files.

I have considered using subversion, but I have read that this is not a good choice for non-code files as it would be keeping a full version of each revision of the file.

Extra Functionality Requested:

- Ability to delete old versions of files when I run out of HHD space on the server.
- Ability to have multiple repos with different permissions
- Command line interface for automatic commits/syncs
- Usage on both windows and linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) with the [zipdoc](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ZipdocExtension) extension.

Mercurial is a distributed version control system, *like git but more user friendly*, that is free, gratis & open source and cross platform. It has a command line interface, hg, by default and a GUI, *tortoise-hg*.

The zipdoc extension version controls the contents of zip format files such as .docx, etc., and handles the zip/unzip process automatically for you so if you check in a docx file it actually stores the component structure and when you check it out builds a fresh docx from it.

Mercurial also handles binary and large files well and has a [Large Files](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/LargefilesExtension) extension for very big files.